# Spring Boot update to 3.2.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-validation

After updating the spring boot version to 3.2.3 test cases were failing with the below error

```
Caused by 'jakarta.validation.UnexceptedTypeExceptin: HV000030: No validator could 
be found for constraint
'jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type 'java.util.UUID'
```

When I tried removing @pattern annotation then test cases are working fine
Is is ok to proceed @Pattern annotation removal or can we replace any other annotation with @Pattern that validates string and also supports @pathvariable annotation that validates UUID

Comment: Could you please add your `pom.xml` ? It looks like a missing dependency issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `@Pattern` will work for `String` based arguments not for a UUID. I'm actually surprised it did work before.